# Why is my Python-based multi-threaded socket downloader slower than my multi-threaded downloader using requests?

Tags: python, sockets, python-requests

I trying to implement a multi-threaded socket downloader(with socks proxy), but it much slower than I expected. So i try to implement it another way (requests). It faster than socket, i wonder why? What cause that? Whcih part i misunderstanding?

```
import logging
import os
import re
import socket
import socks
import threading
import time
from urllib.parse import ParseResult, urlparse, unquote


flag: bool = True


class MyProxy:
    def __init__(self: "MyProxy", protocol: str, host: str, port: int) -> None:
        self.protocol: str = protocol
        self.host: str = host
        self.port: int = port

    def setSocks5Proxy(self: "MyProxy", s: socks.socksocket) -> None:
        s.set_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, self.host, self.port)

    def getHttpProxy(self: "MyProxy") -> str:
        return f"{self.protocol}://{self.host}:{self.port}"


def getHostName(url: str) -> str | None:
    try:
        host: ParseResult = urlparse(url)
        return host.hostname
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"parse url:({url}) error with {e}")


def getFileName(url: str) -> str | None:
    try:
        host: ParseResult = urlparse(url)
        return host.path.split("/")[-1]
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"parseFileName Fail url:({url}) error with {e}")


def download_chunk(
    url: str, start: int, end: int, dataDict: dict, proxy: MyProxy | None = None
):
    host = getHostName(url)
    if not host:
        global flag
        flag = False

    if proxy:
        s = socks.socksocket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        proxy.setSocks5Proxy(s)
    else:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    print(threading.current_thread().ident, "start:", time.time())

    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, 81920000)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 81920000)
    s.connect((host, 80))

    request = (
        f"GET {url} HTTP/1.1\r\nRange: bytes={start}-{end}\r\nHost: {host}\r\n\r\n"
    )
    s.sendall(request.encode())

    response = b""
    while True:
        data = s.recv(81920000)
        if not data:
            break
        response += data

    header_delimiter = b"\r\n\r\n"
    header_end_index = response.find(header_delimiter)
    if header_end_index != -1:
        response = response[header_end_index + len(header_delimiter) :]

    dataDict[start] = response
    print(threading.current_thread().ident, "end:", time.time())
    # 关闭连接
    s.close()


def download(url: str, savePath: str, num_threads: int, proxy: MyProxy | None = None):
    host: str = getHostName(url)
    defaultFileName: str = getFileName(url)
    if proxy:
        s = socks.socksocket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        proxy.setSocks5Proxy(s)
    else:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host, 80))
    request = f"HEAD {url} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {host}\r\n\r\n"
    s.sendall(request.encode())
    response = s.recv(4096).decode()
    filename = re.search(r'Content-Disposition:.*filename="(.+)"', response)
    filename = filename.group(1) if filename else defaultFileName
    filename = unquote(filename)
    content_length = int(response.split("Content-Length: ")[1].split("\r\n")[0])
    # print(f"{response}")
    s.close()
    logging.info(f"文件名: {filename}, 文件大小: {content_length} 字节")


    if os.path.isdir(savePath):
        savePath = os.path.join(savePath, filename)
    elif os.path.isfile(savePath):
        logging.warning(f"savePath({savePath}) is exist, will be cover")
    else:
        logging.error(f"savePath({savePath}) is not exist, will be create")
        os.makedirs(savePath, exist_ok=True)
        savePath = os.path.join(savePath, filename)

    chunk_size = content_length // num_threads
    thread_list: list[threading.Thread] = []

    dataDict: dict = {}

    start = 0
    end = 0
    for i in range(num_threads):
        end = (
            (start + chunk_size - 1) if (i < num_threads - 1) else (content_length - 1)
        )

        thread = threading.Thread(
            target=download_chunk, args=(url, start, end, dataDict, proxy)
        )
        thread.start()
        thread_list.append(thread)
        start = end + 1

    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()

    if not flag:
        logging.error("Download Fail")
        return
    with open(savePath, "wb+") as file:
        for key in sorted(dataDict.keys()):
            file.write(dataDict[key])

    logging.info("Done!")


logging.basicConfig(level="INFO")
startTime = time.time()
logging.info(startTime)
download(
    url="https://download.zerotier.com/dist/ZeroTier%20One.msi",
    # url="https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.6/ubuntu-20.04.6-live-server-amd64.iso",
    savePath="E:",
    num_threads=8,
    proxy=MyProxy("socks5", "127.0.0.1", 10808),
)
logging.info(time.time() - startTime)
```

abover is my socket downloader,

```
import logging
import os
import threading
import time
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse


class MyProxy:
    def __init__(self: "MyProxy", protocol: str, host: str, port: int) -> None:
        self.protocol: str = protocol
        self.host: str = host
        self.port: int = port

    def getHttpProxy(self: "MyProxy") -> str:
        return f"{self.protocol}://{self.host}:{self.port}"


class DownloadThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(
        self: "DownloadThread",
        url: str,
        start_byte: int,
        end_byte: int,
        filename: str,
        proxies: dict | None = None,
    ) -> None:
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.url = url
        self.start_byte = start_byte
        self.end_byte = end_byte
        self.filename = filename
        self.proxies = proxies

    def run(self: "DownloadThread"):
        headers = {"Range": f"bytes={self.start_byte}-{self.end_byte}"}
        response = requests.get( # noqa: S113
            self.url, headers=headers, proxies=self.proxies
        )  
        with open(self.filename, "r+b") as file:
            file.seek(self.start_byte)
            file.write(response.content)
        print(f"Downloaded {self.filename} bytes {self.start_byte}-{self.end_byte}")


def main(url: str, savePath: str, num_threads: int = 1, proxy: MyProxy | None = None):
    filename = urlparse(os.path.basename(url)).path
    # 判断保存路径
    if os.path.isdir(savePath):
        savePath = os.path.join(savePath, filename)
    elif os.path.isfile(savePath):
        logging.warning(f"savePath({savePath}) is exist, will be cover")
    else:
        logging.error(f"savePath({savePath}) is not exist, will be create")
        os.makedirs(savePath, exist_ok=True)
        savePath = os.path.join(savePath, filename)

    proxies = None
    if proxy:
        proxies = {"http": proxy.getHttpProxy(), "https": proxy.getHttpProxy()}

    response = requests.head(url, timeout=60, proxies=proxies)
    total_size = int(response.headers.get("Content-Length", 0))
    print("total_size:", total_size)
    part_size = total_size // num_threads

    threads = []
    with open(savePath, "wb"):
        pass

    for i in range(num_threads):
        start_byte = part_size * i
        end_byte = total_size if i == num_threads - 1 else start_byte + part_size - 1
        thread: DownloadThread = DownloadThread(
            url, start_byte, end_byte, savePath, proxies
        )
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    print("Download completed")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    main(
        # url="https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.6/ubuntu-20.04.6-live-server-amd64.iso",
        # url="https://zenlayer.dl.sourceforge.net/project/anytxt/AnyTXT.Searcher.1.3.1260.Win32_Win64.exe",
        url="https://saimei.ftp.acc.umu.se/cdimage/archive/11.9.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-11.9.0-amd64-netinst.iso",
        savePath="E:\\",
        num_threads=1,
        proxy=MyProxy("http", "127.0.0.1", 10809),
    )
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"耗时: {end_time - start_time} 秒")
```

above is my request downloader,
requests is faster than the socket downloader most of the time.
which part cause my socket downloader such slow?

i try to use s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, 81920000) to increase the buffer size, but it doesn't work

Comment: One obvious problem is that you expect the server to close the connection after the response is done. Only, you ask for the connection to stay open after the response is done (`HTTP/1.1` implies HTTP keep-alive) and thus it will only finish after the server runs into an idle timeout and decides to close the connection - which can be long time after the last byte of the response was actually transmitted. Other aspects are that requests probably announces support for in-transit compression, you don't.